# Can Ruby's Sass gem be manually installed?

Tags: ruby, sass

I work inside a corporate firewall. I am using Windows 10 and have the Ruby 2.4 x64 install.

I need to get the sass gem. I cannot do it through the command line because all external calls such as this are blocked and will not be unblocked for my situation. Is there a place I can manually download the sass gem, and then issue the command to install the gem from a local file?

Comment: you can download it from rubygems ([link](https://rubygems.org/gems/sass))

Comment: you can always run your own gem server. http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/ — there are other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in the same position and use two techniques

1. through the firewall
   See my answer at [installing-gems-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903005/installing-gems-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall/9021630?s=1%7C97.4893#9021630)
2. from a local file

You download the gem from https://rubygems.org/downloads/sass-3.5.4.gem
You can put the file in your ruby\bin folder and delete it later.

Then you cd to your bin folder and install it in the console with the command

```
gem install sass-3.5.4.gem --local
```

the 3.5.4 is the current version.
If there are dependencies (other gems) you need to first download them as wel.
Can't see what these are because on this machine I'm still using Ruby MRI 1.9.3 and the current version of sass requires Ruby 2.0.0

See also my answer here

[deploy-a-ruby-gem-local-without-using-git-or-internet-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555141/deploy-a-ruby-gem-local-without-using-git-or-internet-access/35581275?s=1%7C63.6473#35581275)

Comment: I did this and got this: ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'sass-listen' (~> 4.0.0) in any repository.

Comment: see wat I wrote about dependencies, sass-listen is one of them, you need to download them as well and put them in the same folder, the easiest thing to do is first install the gem on a normal to the internet connected pc, copy the list of gems that are installed as well and copy these gems to your server behind the firewall

Comment: This is a great answer and got me close. However, it still did not work for me due to corporate restrictions on my computer. My end goal is SASS, so I might explore another way to compile it. Thanks!